# Why use AngularJs .constant() if I can declare JS const?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants

I'm working on an AngularJS project where there is a `.constant()` provider to declare some basic information used across the whole project. For example, a definition of cookie name. Ex.:

```
.constant('appConst', { 
    cookie: 'CookieName',
    ...
});
```

But the same thing can be done by declaring a `const`, ex.:

```
const appConst = {
    cookie: 'CookieName',
    ...
}
```

So, what is the advatage of using the `.constant` provider instead of just declaring a `const`? I know one of the reasons is because we don't expect the value to change. But isn't this the same objective of a `const`?

Comment: http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/constants/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `const` keyword only makes it so you cannot reassign the variable, it doesn't make any object you initially assign to it immutable. So in your example with:

```
const appConst = {
    cookie: 'CookieName',
    ...
}
```

You would still be able to change the value of `cookie`. You just wouldn't be allowed to do something like this:

```
appConst = { // My new object };
```

The values in the angular `.constant()` can also still be changed, so they're not constant in the common use of the word "constant". At least not when you use it like this:

```
.constant('appConst', { 
    cookie: 'CookieName',
    ...
});
```

So if you for instance do like this and change the value within a controller

```
app.controller('myController', function(appConst){
    appConst.cookie = 'NewCookieName';
})
```

the change would be reflected anywhere you inject `appConst` after this controller was constructed.

You can't "reassign" `appConst` in this case though, that action would just be ignored, so it is constant in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

1- `const` is new in ES6, so you may need to transpiler your code for supporting old browsers.

2- `const` is block-scoped, so within a scenario, you define a constant in `A.js`, will be not able to use it at `B.js` unless you're using a module bundler, so we went back to the topic *1-*.

The main purpose of AngularJS having this native is to able you to share it between controllers, services, and directives, using its dependency injection system.